# Resolving the Mesos Leading Master

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos

We're using Mesos to run jobs on a cluster.  We're using haproxy to point, e.g.,  `mesos.seanmcl.com` to a Mesos Master.

If that Master happens to not be the leader, the UI will redirect the browser, after a **delay**, to the leader so you can see the running jobs.  For various reasons (UI speed, avoiding ports blocked by a firewall), I'd really like to programmatically discover the host with the leader.  I can not figure out how to do this.

I grepped around in the Zookeeper files for Mesos, but only found small bits of host information like the *IP address*.  Is there any way, via Mesos CLI, Zookeeper CLI, etc. to find the Mesos Leading Master?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the approach used by `Mesos` itself to determine the `Leading Master` using `Zookeeper` communications.

The idea is to use the membership labels in `Zookeeper` communications to determine the `Leading Master`, cache it and use it for the subsequent requests. Check the following links for the implementation:

- [Leading Master Detector Header](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/master/detector.hpp)
- [Leading Master Detector Implementation](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/master/detector.cpp)

Here's an example code using `CLI`:

- [Mesos-Resolve](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/src/cli/resolve.cpp)

**Edit:** Alternatively you can use the command `resolve` in `Mesos-CLI` which returns the `host/port` for the current `Leading Master` which uses `Mesos-Resolve` code located in the `Mesos` core:

- [Resolve Command](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-cli/blob/master/mesos/cli/resolve.py)

Comment: This worked using mesos-resolve.  It took me a moment to figure out the zookeeper url format.  Something like this works:  mesos-resolve zk://zookeeper.seanmcl.com:2181/mesos

Comment: The python api also works well.  import mesos.cli as mesos...        mesos.resolve('zk://zookeeper.seanmcl.com:2181/mesos').strip()...

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful :)