# Zookeeper leader not the Mesos Master

Tags: centos, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I am new to Mesos and I have built a mesos cluster of three CentOS 7 nodes (all three nodes acting as masters and slaves) in a local hypervisor. 
The nodes are named mesos1, mesos2 and mesos3

I have this running with Zookeeper marathon and chronos. I was wondering how I can check who is the acting mesos master at any given time, when I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657253/resolving-the-mesos-leading-master)!

I also found out that I could find the leading master of mesos by adding 
    /redirect 
to the endpoint.

So when I tried that, Mesos UI at 5050 pport redirected me to the node mesos2.

However, when I tried to find the zookeeper leader using this command:
    /opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status
I got the following response that the leader was mesos3

```
[root@mesos3 ~]# /opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Mode: leader
```

I am confused: Shouldn't the mesos master be the node that is indicated as leader by zookeeper?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesos and Zookeeper have distinct concepts of leadership and it sounds like you are mixing the two up. You are running three instances of the Zookeeper server process which form a quorum, and three Mesos master processes which also form a quorum that happen to be on the same set of servers. Mesos uses Zookeeper for storing state and other critical functions but **Zookeeper's cluster leadership is in no way related to Mesos cluster leadership**. They do use very similar terminology so it is easy to see how they can be mixed up.